# Run queries to MS SQL server with strange table names

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

For an application we need to connect to an SQL Server 2008 to do some queries.

I run the queries in PHP on an Codeigniter Framework. I get access to this SQL database by an program called "Microsoft SQL server management studio". The tables have strange names with dollar signs: `TRP$Lease Car` for example.

The studio get data by this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *
  FROM [Mdatabase].[dbo].[TRP$Lease Car]
```

When I run this query in my PHP installation it fails on the `$` sign:

```
$data = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM dbo.TRP$Lease Car");
```

Like this:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: Lease
>
> Filename: views/welcome_message.php
>
> Line Number: 5 A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 42S02
>
> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object
>   name 'dbo.TRP'.

How do I need to call these tables when running an query from my PHP?

**EDIT**

The problem only appears on tables with an space in the name...  An query with `TRP$Invoice` works. In this case `TRP$Lease Car` is the problem I think..

Comment: Did you try adding the brackets[] around the table name in your string? `query("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TRP$LeaseCar]");`

Comment: The problem only appears on tables with an space in the name...  An query with "TRP$Invoice" works..

Comment: @DanielE. - The root issue is the PHP variable substitution, before the SQL query runs.  The SQL error is a *result* of the PHP mistake.  *(See the answer below.)*

Comment: Hehe thats a good one, but a space in a table name in SQL still needs to be bracketed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you have your query in double-quotes.  When PHP encounters a double-quoted string containing `$something`, it will treat `$something` as a variable and attempt to substitute its value.  In this case, you have `TPR$Lease` in your string - PHP attempts to resolve variable `$Lease` - which you haven't defined - and gives you the warning message you indicated.  There are two ways of dealing with it.

1. Escape the dollar sign: `"select * from TPR\$Lease"` - thus telling PHP that you really do need the dollar sign there.
2. Use single-quoted string: `'select * from TPR$Lease'` - php will not do variable substitution in single-quoted strings.

Obviously, adjust the actual SQL statements according to your specific schema.

**EDIT:** if your table name contains spaces, then you have to use square brackets `[ ... ]` around the tabla name:

```
"select * from [TPR\$Lease Car]"
```

Note however that this is MS SQL specific syntax.  This will not work on most other database engines, as (to my knowledge) only MS allows spaces in table names.

Comment: @JelleP - Have you actually tried this?  It's the right answer, even after your edits.

Comment: @AleksG - It would also still be worth protecting the table names in `[]` when they're this 'strange'.

Comment: Your comment solves the PHP problem. Thanks for that one. But the SQL error stays with: SELECT * FROM dbo.TPR\$Lease Car"

Comment: @JelleP You need to actualy _think_, not just copy/paste somebody else's code.  You used square brackets in your very first statement that you put directly into MS SQL - so use the same in your PHP.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Hmm brackets does not help. Must be something like that indeed.

Comment: Got it. I used dbo. before it and that is an problem while using brackets. Your answer is good! Thanks!